# Opening and closing a file returns syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am making some check-in system, just in case I want to build like a bot. But I am stuck building because my code returns syntax error. Can someone help me fix this?

I am making this code on Repl.it, one of the online IDE. I couldn't test it on eclipse because my python just isn't working.

```
import datetime

#This is where Name variable goes
#checkin = open(check-in.txt", "r")

i=0
while True:
  it = input("Type in input: ")
  if it == "Check-in list":
    checkin = open("check-in.txt", "r")
    if checkin.mode == "r":
        contents = checkin.read()
        print(contents)
        checkin.close()
  elif it == "Check-in":
    checkin = open("check-in.txt", "a")
    if checkin.mode == "a":
      currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
      checkin.write((str(i+1) +". " + username + ":" + str(currentDT))
    checkin.close()
```

## Where error happens

```
checkin.close()
```

I have expect the output of "Type in input: " and when I type Check-in, the program should add number order, name, and time.

The output is: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: The parens are not balanced in `checkin.write((str(i+1) +". " + username + ":" + str(currentDT))`

Comment: repl.it is not really an IDE to begin with - any IDE would have pointed out that you're missing a parenthesis. "Because my python just isn't working" - that's probably the problem you should be focusing on solving first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are parentheses missing from `checkin.write((str(i+1) +". " + username + ":" + str(currentDT))`. Here is a fixed version: `checkin.write((str(i+1) +". " + username + ":" + str(currentDT)))`

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are not balanced. Add an extra `)` after your `checkin.write(...` line.